# Who can advise me on how SWAT teams and commanders work?

Tags: crime

I am working on a techno-thriller novel revolving about a hostage situation during a bank robbery. The twist is that the perpetrator is not present at the scene. He has sent a remote controlled robot into the bank with a bomb.

I have a pretty good understanding of police procedures. I've worked with the police for several years, even have cops in my family. However a prolonged hostage situation is a very rare occurrence, particularly in my little Eastern European country, so none of my contacts can answer a good couple of things on how decisions are made, how various experts consult on matters and what would cause a SWAT officer do or don't do certain things. I believe there can't be a major difference on how such serious situations are handled in any modern country.

I've tried asking on Quora already, but I got zero answers. There are plenty of cops there, but they don't respond. They probably think that I'm actually plotting a real robbery.

So guys, can someone recommend me someone who would help me out on a few specific questions? Not vague and broad ones like "how SWATs work in general", but something like "if the hostage negotiator suggests not to take action, can the commander ignore it", and so on.

Comment: Try https://little-details.livejournal.com/ They're a big community, usually they have answers to the strangest questions.

Comment: Tomcat? Te? Itt? I think you should look up 4chan's /k/ board. They're the experts. Also, [GURPS](https://img.fireden.net/tg/image/1450/54/1450541260173.pdf) can help, to an extent. (it has an appendix for research materials)

Comment: Itt. But more on Stack Overflow. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a document called [SWAT Standards For Law Enforcement Agencies](https://ntoa.org/massemail/swatstandards.pdf) that has the objective of establishing:

> SWAT Standards to serve as an efficient core set of concepts,
>   principles and policies to standardize and enhance the delivery of
>   tactical law enforcement services.

I skimmed the first third of the 56 page document and it seems to give the kind of information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So, the main advise from me would be: Try to research information. But apparently you have done that already.

My next advise is split in two parts:

1. More research: There are so many countries with so many SWAT teams. And I think every land handles it differently than yours. So if you are writing in a special land, it could be useful to research the ways, things are handled there
2. Try to research from people who were in a hostage situation. They have kind of an inner view, how the situation happened.

But as always in these kind of special circumstances: Research form every possible source is the best kind of answer.